# How to define CHECK constraint for a Postgres DOMAIN that is based on a composite type

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

I would like to define a Postgres domain with check constraints based on a custom composite type.

An example for a naive approach would be this:

```sql
CREATE TYPE raw_comp_foo AS (
    min_value    integer,
    max_value    integer
);
CREATE DOMAIN comp_foo AS raw_comp_foo
CHECK (VALUE.min_value < VALUE.max_value);
```

However, I get the error message `missing FROM-clause entry for table "value"`.
How can I achieve the desired constraint in the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the composite value in parentheses:

```sql
CREATE DOMAIN comp_foo AS raw_comp_foo
CHECK ((VALUE).min_value < (VALUE).max_value);
```

The issue is explained in [Accessing Composite Types.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-ACCESSING)

Comment: Oh wow. So this was only a syntax problem after all? And there I was, assuming it was a semantic problem. Could you maybe add a documentation reference stating that VALUE should be put in parentheses?